# A doubt on the notation of Frigola et al (2013) of Gaussian Processes(GP) for a State-Space model?

Tags: gaussian-process, state-space-models

[image]

The picture above is from Frigola et al (2013) - Bayesian Inference and Learning in Gaussian Process State-Space Models with Particle MCMC.

In this paper, the authors later define $\mathbf{f}_t=f(\mathbf{x}_{t-1})$, and here lies my misunderstanding...

Let me explain better my doubt. When $f(\mathbf{x}_t)$ follows a unidimensional GP, we have for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$

$(f(\mathbf{x}_1),...,f(\mathbf{x}_n))\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,k(X,X'))$, 
where $f(\cdot) \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\mu = (m(\mathbf{x}_1),...,m(\mathbf{x}_1))'$.

However, when we write $\mathbf{f}_t=f(\mathbf{x}_{t-1})$, it seems we are using a univariate function to define vector $\mathbf{f}_t$. How can this be?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I did not find this explicitly stated in the paper, it seems that $f$ is actually intended to be a multiple output Gaussian process (possibly with independent components) - so that a realization is a function from $\mathbb{R}^{n_x}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n_x}$ and thus $\mathbb{f}_t = f(\mathbf{x}_t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n_x}$. Note that:

1. In the first author's PhD thesis [1], Section 3.1, similar notation is used to define a Gaussian process state-space model, and on p. 27 the following remark appears:

> Note that the covariance function $\kappa(\cdot, \cdot)$ returns a matrix
>   of the same size as the state in an analogous manner to multi-output Gaussian
>   processes (Rasmussen and Williams, 2006).

2. In an earlier paper considering Gaussian process state-space models, Turner et al. [2] (reference [2] of the case paper), "independent GPs are used for each target dimension of $f$" (p. 869, last paragraph of the left-hand-side column). Which is a special case of a multiple-output GP.

#### References

[1] Roger Frigola-Alcalde (2015) Bayesian Time Series Learning
with Gaussian Processes. PhD thesis, University of Camridge. http://www.rogerfrigola.com/doc/thesis.pdf

[2] Ryan Turner, Marc Deisenroth, and Carl Rasmussen (2010). "State-space inference and learning with Gaussian processes." AISTATS 2010, http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/turner10a/turner10a.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the notation here. When the author say
\begin{align}
x_{t+1}| f_t \sim \mathcal{N}(x_{t+1}|f_t, Q),
\end{align}
this implies that $x_{t+1}$ is distributed with mean $f_t$ and covariance $Q$, where $f_t$ is obtained from the state evolution equation given in (1a), i.e.,
\begin{align}
x_{t+1} = f(x_t,u_t) + v_t.
\end{align}
As $f$ depends on $t$, they denote the mean of $x_{t+1}$ as $f_t$ which is nothing but $\mathbb{E}(x_{t+1}) = \mathbb{E}(f(x_t,u_t)) = f_t$ if $v_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,Q)$. Therefore $x_{t+1}| f_t \sim \mathcal{N}(x_{t+1}|f_t, Q)$.

An easy way to understand this by assuming $f(x_t,u_t)$ takes the form
\begin{align}
f(x_t, u_t) = A x_t + B u_t
\end{align}

Comment: Maxtron, thank you for your answer. I hope I'm not being too blunt, but do you know what's a gaussian process? I have no problem understanding what you've just written. My doubt is that there seems to exist an inconsistency in the dimensions of what you've just written and the definition of $f(x_t)$ being a Gaussian Process with a scalar covariance function $k(x_t, x_t')$

Comment: The Gaussian distributions here are not univariate. They are [multivariate Gaussian distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) where $x_t$ is an  $n$-dimensional vector. Does this make things clear?

Comment: Here's a tutorial on [Gaussian processes](http://katbailey.github.io/post/gaussian-processes-for-dummies/). If you are looking for more depth in understanding Gaussian processes, read [GPML](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/) textbook written by Carl Edward Rasmussen and Christopher K. I. Williams. I'd definitely recommend Chap. 2 and 3.

Comment: Maxtron, I've edited my question. See if it's now easier to understand my doubt.

Comment: I understand what's a GP (I think), and what's a Multivariate Gaussian Distribution.

Comment: I think the root cause of confusion is the function $f$ which you are using to define the probability function as well as the function that depends on the state evolution matrix. The probability function (denoted by $p$ not $f$) $p: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ where as the state evolving function $f: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N$. I hope this clears your confusion.

Comment: In the example above, the state evolution function is $f_t$ where as the probability function is $f$. Both are not the same. $f_t$ takes the form of an affine function, like the one in my solution. $f$ is a multivariate normal distribution.